# Search a mysql table through another table

Tags: php, mysql, search

I would really appreciate it if you can just give me a way or an idea on how to solve my problem:

I have a table that contains my users information like name,email.....etc. And the row's id like 1,2,3 (auto increment).

And another table that checks if the first member is a second member friend, it goes like : mem1 id, mem2 id, date added, row's id...etc

And what I want to make a regular HTML form, that let's he user searches for his friends. Like if jack types the name of his friend John, he gets whether John is his friend or not according to the second table.

I would be really joyful if someone can help me, I'd really be happy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with a JOIN:

```
SELECT m2.name FROM member_relations AS f
JOIN members AS m1 ON m1.id = f.mem1
JOIN members AS m2 ON m2.id = f.mem2
WHERE m1.name = 'Jack' AND m2.name = 'John'
```

Assuming you already know the current user's ID you can simplify it:

```
SELECT m.name FROM member_relations AS f
JOIN members AS m ON m.id = f.mem2
WHERE f.mem1 = {ID} AND m.name = 'John'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.name as friend_name, friends.friend_id as friend_id FROM 
users, (SELECT mem1 as friend_id FROM friends WHERE friends.mem1=$userid   UNION SELECT mem2 as friend_id FROM friends WHERE friends.mem2=$userid) as user_friends 
WHERE user_friends.friend_id=users.id
```

This query should fetch all friend's names and user id's from the tables. Just Render the result as json and use ajax to fetch it. Check out autocomplete on jquery UI
http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax: when user enters first value, do an asynchronous call to php script which will search for the data in database and return results.